# Regex to make all new lines the same

Tags: c#, regex, newline, linefeed

I have to format the programming code that several people have dumped in. So I have to make sure that there are not double spaces, all classes have a comment etc.. Anyways I am having a hard time creating this find and replaces because of the new line... In other words some chunks have:

```
   // this is some comment \r\n
   // some other line \r\n
```

other chunks just have:

```
  // bla bla bla \n
  // bla bla bla \n
```

other chunks

```
 // bla bla bla \r
 // bla bla bla \r
```

lastly other chunks have

```
 // bla bla \n\r
 // bla bla \n\r
```

because of this differences I am having a harder time to create the regexes.

**So my question is how can I replace all possibilities (`\r\n`, `\n`, `\r`, `\n\r`) into \r\n? so that:**

```
        var a = "\n\r\n\rHelloWorld";
        var b = "\r\n\n\rHelloWorld";
        var c = "\r\rHelloWorld";
        var d = "\n\nHelloWorld";
```

**all turn out to be:  `"\r\n\r\nHelloWorld"`**

note that all variables a, b, c, and d =

```
->
->
-> HelloWorld
```

they all look the same on visual studio...

Comment: StyleCop and Ctrl + K + D should do.

Comment: thanks that seems to work but that removes some of the indentation on some parts...

Comment: It reformats the code according to the Visual Studio settings - these _can_ be changed.

Comment: If you're doing it inside Visual Studio, you don't need a regex. Just use File->Save->Advanced Save Settings, set the line endings you want to use (Windows, in this case), and then save the file. It will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to do is replace CR possibly followed by LF, or LF possibly followed by CR:

Search: `\r\n?|\n\r?`

Replace: `\r\n`

Comment: I did:  `static string MakeAllNewLinesTheSame ( string input )
        {
            string replace = "\r\n";
            return Regex.Replace ( input, @"(\r\n?|\n\r?)", replace );
        }`